# Slow Moving Objects (Visual)

Tags: java

When I try to move graphical objects across the screen at steps which are not whole numbers (for example, 0.5 pixels per frame) this results in choppy and 'laggy' movement; as the object will simply move 1 pixel every two frames.

I understand why this is happening as the x / y values of an object must be Integers, but I wonder if there is anyway to create smooth slow movement, such as there is in Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Graphics2D`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) allows you to draw at sub-pixel accuracy and as long as your actual object is drawn using its primitive (as opposed to being a fixed bitmap), this should actually have a visible effect.

Make sure that the [`KEY_ANTIALIASING`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_ANTIALIASING) [rendering hint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint%28java.awt.RenderingHints.Key,%20java.lang.Object%29) is set to [`VALUE_ANTIALIASING_ON`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems like what I've been looking for.