# Sub-Pixel Graphical Movement

Tags: java

I've been reading about sub-pixel accuracy but could not find a way to do this.

**Q:** How can I move a `BufferedImage` across a `Canvas` at non-integer speeds without stuttering?

I can logically understand how the process happens - slight resizing with Anti-Aliasing, but I cannot recreate this in Java. (I've had experience with Flash where such an effect is created by default on most visual objects.)

*Note: I've submitted a **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389279/slow-moving-objects-visual)** about the subject before, but after searching for further information I still couldn't implement what I learned.*

If it is not too much trouble, a simple example would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** This is how I understood the effect can be achieved, though it doesn't work for me:

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height));
```

There is no visible change between double and similar int values at the x & y fields, and when I try to create very slow movement (system time based, for example) I see the rectangle doing nothing but moving a single pixel every now and then.

Comment: Why `Canvas` ? and nothing from `javax.swing`? - that may be the reason. Did you see [this](http://today.java.net/today/2006/02/23/SmoothAnimationDemo/com/sun/animation/SmoothAnimation.java) example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ButtonUITest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169647/when-does-a-jpanel-paint-or-repaint-its-child-components/5170911#5170911) offers a side-by-side comparison of the effect.

[image]

On many platforms, it's possible to zoom the display to see more. On Mac OS X, <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> works, as does `/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools/Pixie.app`. On other platforms supporting Java, [`Zoom`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742731/java-how-to-draw-constantly-changing-graphics/3742841#3742841) is a handy tool for examining anti-aliased pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I cannot see how this is related to my question. I can create AA effects on shapes, but I cannot create smooth movement when an object is moved a non-whole amount of pixels every frame.

Comment: Ah, you were looking for an animated demo. You'd have to move the `Rectangle2D` coordinates by a fraction of a pixel in each frame to see the effect.

Comment: Which is exactly what I have done, yet there is no visible effect!

Comment: I hope this is what you asked. Here is my render method:
http://notepad.cc/xukoscu57.

WIDTH and HEIGHT are the size of my content pane. (JPanel in a JFrame)
This code basically moves a rectangle back and forth **very** slowly and it is easily visible that every few moments it simply jumps 1 pixel forward without any visible difference in between.

Comment: No, this fragment is not an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), but it reveals that you are drawing with integer coordinates. Use [`draw(Shape s)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw%28java.awt.Shape%29).

Comment: I'm not sure if pictures this nature should be distibuted to the public forums +1

Answer (score 1):

Try also setting the following rendering hint (as well as anti-aliasing):

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

Comment: This seems to make quite an impact, but I can't tell whether it's for better or for worse. I can definitely still detect stuttering though.